# PHPUnit fails when logging in user

Tags: 8, testing

I've got a custom module and have the auto generated `LoadTest` but it is not working. This is a functional test.

```
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser(['administer site configuration']);
    $this->drupalLogin($this->user); // Breaks here
  }

  public function testLoad() {
    $this->drupalGet(Url::fromRoute('<front>'));
    $this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals(200);
  }
```

Running this test returns :

```
1) Drupal\Tests\weekly_digest\Functional\LoadTest::testLoad
User <em class="placeholder">belwfS3e</em> successfully logged in.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/app/web/core/tests/Drupal/TestTools/PhpUnitCompatibility/PhpUnit7/TestCompatibilityTrait.php:18
/app/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/UiHelperTrait.php:254
/app/web/modules/custom/weekly_digest/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php:35
```

When I comment out the `drupalLogin` call the test succeeds.

The fail is on this line

```
$this->assertTrue($this->drupalUserIsLoggedIn($account), new FormattableMarkup('User %name successfully logged in.', ['%name' => $account->getAccountName()]));
```

And if you look at the error from above it's from the TestCompatibilityTrait which had some pretty wacky deprecation errors.

Here is my phpunit env

```
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>

    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled"/>

    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://changelog.lndo.site/"/>
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://drupal8:drupal8@database/drupal8"/>

    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="web/sites/simpletest/browser_output"/>
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_BASE_URL" value=""/>

    <!-- Example for changing the driver class for mink tests MINK_DRIVER_CLASS value: 'Drupal\FunctionalJavascriptTests\DrupalSelenium2Driver' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_CLASS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to mink tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to phantomjs tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to webdriver tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER value: '["chrome", { "chromeOptions": { "w3c": false } }, "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"]' For using the Firefox browser, replace "chrome" with "firefox" -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER" value=''/>
```

This is using lando.
Why would I be getting these failures? It accesses the site just fine, it seems to be checking if the user is logged in that's causing the issue but I can't find out why.

Comment: If you move the login to the actual test method instead of doing the login in setUp, does it do any difference for you?

Comment: @johndevman Nope, same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same behaviour, and found that while the `phpunit.xml` had `SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL` set to my site URL locally, in the Lando appserver the environment variable was set to `https://appserver_nginx`.

Even setting `SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL="http://appserver_nginx"` in a Lando `env_file` directive didn't resolve this.

When I used `lando ssh` into the appserver container and executed `phpunit web/modules/contrib/modulename`, I saw the same error. If I set the environment variable manually using `export SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL=http://appserver_nginx` then ran the tests again, the login step worked.

---

The eventual solution I used, from [here](https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/2283#issuecomment-758557622), was to modify `phpunit.xml` to contain this line:

```xml
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://appserver_nginx" force="true"/>
```

And to execute PHPUnit in Lando with this tooling:

```yaml
tooling:
  phpunit:
    service: appserver
    cmd: "php /app/vendor/bin/phpunit -c /app/phpunit.xml"
```

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674749/failing-drupal-8-functional-tests-on-drupallogin
- https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/2283